# strfind for string array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, whitespace

I have a cell array, x, and each row of which is a string array.
For instance,

```
>>ab = x{2};
>>ab
ans =
  910        Flow’S Equation
```

Clearly, this string has a pattern: a numerical value and a text string are separated by some empty spaces. With respect to this example, when I type

```
>> ab(2)
  ans =
    1
>> ab(3)
  ans =
    0
>> ab(6)
  ans =
    F
```

In my code, I need automatically check the starting position of text string, which is the one for "F" and the end position of numerical value, which is the one for "0".  I use

```
>> x = strfind(ab, ' ');
```

For this example, I expect it give me the positions of "space" as

> > 4  5  12

In stead, it just gives me 12 without outputing 4 and 5

I think the problem is that the fourth and fifth entries of ab are not "space", How can I know what are they? When I type

```
>> ab(4)
 ans =
```

The output is nothing, just like what "space" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out what char `ab(4)` is, convert the char to numerical form by

```
double( ab(4) )
```

For `double(ab(4))=9`, it's a `TAB`. If your string is ASCII, you may want to check [ASCII control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_characters) and [ASCII printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_printable_characters) for the mapping.

However, to find the beginning of the text string, using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) may be a better idea:

```
string_begin = min( regexp(ab, '[^\d\s]') )
```

`regexp(ab, '[^\d\s]')` returns the locations of all characters that are neither numbers nor white spaces, and the minimum of the locations should be where the text begins.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
double(ab(4))
```

It's probably a non-printable ascii character

Another way you can see what is in the variable is

```
sprintf('[%d]',sprintf('Some\n\r\ttext'))
ans =

[83][111][109][101][10][13][9][116][101][120][116]
```

or in your case

ans =

```
sprintf('[%d]', ab );
```

If you're trying to find words in the string that are separated by a space or tab character you can use:

```
regexp(x{2},'[\t ]','split')
```

Comment: double(ab(4)) returns a value of 9. Is this a special character? I have more than one thousand rows, and each of which has the similar scenario. If this unprintable ascii character always can be transferred to 9, I can write a if-logic to know its position. Otherwise, how can I do? Thanks.

Comment: 9 is the horizontal tab character.

Comment: Do you need the position of the strings or the strings themselves? It's somewhat a workaround, but you could use C=textscan(x{index},'%d\t%s'); to scan the number and other string into a cell array C, which you already seem to know how to work with.